# Div border on hover pushes floated content

Tags: css, css-float

I have 4 `float: left` div containers like so...

[image]

I want to display a border when a div is hovered over. However, when I hover over the first or second div, it pushes the bottom div to the left...

[image]

I tried adding margin and padding to the div's, but nothing seemed to work.

```
.div
{
  width: 33%;
}

.div:hover
{
  boder: solid 1px #EEE;
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example. And how about a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a backround coloured or transparent border on the initial state and the size of the box won't change.

```
.div {
  width: 32%; // (33% + 1px border) * 3 = likely more than the width of the container
  border: solid 1px transparent;
}

.div:hover {
  boder: solid 1px #EEE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to have a border all of the time, but make it the same color as the background when not hovered.

For example:

```
.div
{
  width: 33%;
  border: solid 1px #FFF;
}
.div:hover
{
  border: solid 1px #EEE;
}
```

EDIT: Alternatively if an invisible border won't work (gradient background, etc.) you can add 1px padding when not hovered and make it 0px padding when hovered.

For example:

```
.div
{
  width: 33%;
  padding: 1px;
}
.div:hover
{
  border: solid 1px #EEE;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: So you can! I did not realize. Thanks!